Is exhaustive-listing が here acting like a topic marker?
This comes from a podcast where the speaker is describing the two reasons why feeling Mono no aware is difficult to do, with 1. there is no time due to responsibilities and 2. that with the influence of entertainment and distractions there is no time to think about your own life deeply and doing so results in grief:

なかなか難しいと思います。今はものの哀れを私たちが感じることって。
理由は二つあって，一つ目は時間がない。二つ目は考える習慣がないってことですね。
一つ目の時間がないっていうのはその言葉の通りで，宿題がいっぱいあったりとか仕事がいっぱいあったりとか。
本当に毎日時間に追われて生活をしていますよね。もう家に帰ってきたらもう疲れて寝るだけだと。
後はこの二つ目のこう考える習慣っていうのが，やっぱりエンターテインメントが多すぎるので自分の人生について深く考える時間がないし，
そんなことやってたら心が壊れちゃう。

I've noticed that this speaker in particular uses というのは and というのが generally in places where I would more expect regular は and が, but I've come to the conclusion that it is partially likely a speech habit and that he tends to talk about things more conceptually which I feel という adds a nuance to.
However, I still struggle interpreting everything from 後は to 心が壊れちゃう, because of the way he brings up the second reason. Comparing with the first reason where he uses っていうのは, this makes more sense to me because I interpret the は part as not actually contributing to the "logic" of the sentence because he is not actually ending the sentence with any kind of だ that the usual XというのはY(という)ことだ structure has.
In essence I understand reason one this way:

"As for this reason of "there's no time"... as the name suggests, you
have a lot of homework and work. You're really living pressed for time
daily. You think "When I come home I'm already tired and I'll just
sleep."

But with reason two I see it like:

"Also this (precise) second reason of "a practice where you think like
this"... after all there's too much entertainment so there's no time
for thinking deeply about your life and if you did that sort of thing
you'd get very sad."

So I get that the が is exhaustive, but it feels like the first part of the sentence ending with っていうのが is, like the first reason, not actually a logical part of a "X is Y" sentence (this is why I'm adding a "..." in my translation) but rather it also feels like it's announcing a topic just using が to emphasize what comes before it (rather than a similar sentence like this).
My only other thought is that there is some implied ということだ at the end of both of these reasons and that I'm wrong about は not participating in a "logical" structure here. Either way, I'm just not fully sure how to break down the second reason.
Spotify link to podcast here, starts at 26:53.

"the first reason where he uses っていうのは … he is not actually ending the sentence with any kind of だ" — で in その言葉の通りで is a form of だ, right?

Oh yes you are right about that. But omitting that part isn’t crucial because what follows is also his interpretation of the first reason

That is to say, I see what follows the とか and such as also part of the interpretation which is why I imagine an implied ということだ at the end. Either way I don’t think removing that part would make it ungrammatical

Were they talking about entertainment before that?

No, they just brought it up as a random example of things that eat up time

Is this a transcription by you?

後はこの二つ目のこう考える習慣っていうのがやっぱりエンターテインメントが多すぎるので自分の人生について深く考える時間がないし、そんなことやってたら心が壊れちゃう。

As you have correctly noticed, if you interpret this whole thing as one long sentence, you will end up with a weird sentence with subject-predicate mismatch. There is no predicate that corresponds to 習慣(っていうの).
Instead, you can try splitting this as two:

後はこの二つ目のこう「考える習慣(がない)」っていうのが(ね/大事で/言いたいことで)。
And the second one, um, this "(lack of) thinking habit" thing!
やっぱり、エンターテインメントが多すぎるので自分の人生について深く考える時間がないし、そんなことやってたら心が壊れちゃう。
After all, there's too much entertainment so there's no time for thinking deeply about your life, and if you did that sort of thing, your mind will break down.

The が in bold is indeed an exhaustive-listing が if you need to classify it. It's there to "single out" the second reason among the two. Along with やっぱり, he may be thinking the second reason is more fundamental.
That being said, I feel が used like this has a very weak "exhaustive-listing" function. The following two texts are both natural, and sound almost identical to me.

ここに3個のボールが並んでいます。1個めは青で、2個めは赤で、3個めは緑です。
ここに3個のボールが並んでいます。1個めが青で、2個めが赤で、3個めが緑です。

In this case, the three が are used simply to move on from one target to another. Likewise, in your context, whether he is putting more emphasis on the second reason ("lack of thinking habit") depends on the broader context and the intonation. He may have used が simply to move on to the second topic. I tentatively added "(大事で/言いたいことで)" after the が above, but this implication may or may not be there.
EDIT: I checked the actual audio, and I think it's used simply to move on to the next target, as in my ball example. 考える習慣がないっていうのが had no corresponding predicate. You can think the sentence ends there with an implied predicate, or you can think this is a bit messy sentence, which is undeniably common in speech.

Yes, checking the audio reveals that the やっぱり belongs to the second half (I did transcribe this myself) as he pauses briefly after the が.

@whatyouexpect Thanks, I edited my answer.

@whatyouexpect Please see my edit.

Another possibility is この2つ目のこの考える習慣がないっていうのが（どういうことかというと）

@Detaroit Yes, that makes sense, too. The implied predicate can be anything. It can be taken as a minor sentence whose main purpose is to move on to the next reason.

@naruto And in the case of どういうことかというと it is not implied the second reason is more important.

@Detaroit Correct. I no longer feel such a nuance after listening to the actual audio. But it's still technically an exhaustive-listing-ga, so depending on the intonation, such a nuance could have been conveyed. Do you think my answer is unclear in this regard?

Well, a bit unclear, I guess. You can emphasize that what you are going to elaborate on is X and not any other, depending on how you pronounce Xがどういうことかというと, but I don't think it means X is more important than other topics, just saying.

And I guess Xがどういうことかというと makes a subordinate clause, and thus the が here can be neutral-descriptive, but I'm not informed well about the distinction between the exhaustive listing and the neutral description, so I may be totally wrong.

The presence of やっぱり suggests the speaker had in mind the current situation where people have all kinds of entertainment and rarely reflect on themselves before this utterance. が adds a slight sense that their second point is precisely because of that.
The nuance is so subtle I (native) would never stop to think why the first one is は and the second is が.
From this script alone there seems no reason to believe something like 大事で is omitted.

In case something like emphasis in pronunciation is important, I added the link to the podcast w/ timestamp.
